# why is casper.on('click' ...) not triggering?

Tags: casperjs

Following is a minimal casper script that does a Google query.  I've added `casper.on('click' ...)` prior to running the script, but it doesn't appear to get triggered.

What am I missing?

```
// File: google_click_test.js
"use strict";

var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.on('click', function(css) {
    casper.echo('casper.on received click event ' + css);
});

// ================================================================
// agenda starts here

casper.start('https://google.com', function g01() {
    casper.echo('seeking main page');
});

casper.then(function a02() {
    casper.waitForSelector(
        'form[action="/search"]',
        function() { 
            casper.echo("found search form"); 
        },
        function() { 
            casper.echo("failed to find search form"); 
            casper.exit(); 
        });
});

casper.then(function a03() {
    casper.fillSelectors('form[action="/search"]', {
        'input[title="Google Search"]' : 'casperjs'
    }, false);
});

casper.then(function a04() {
    casper.click('form[action="/search"] input[name="btnG"]')
    casper.echo('clicked search button');
});

casper.run();
```

Output:

Here's the output.  I would expect to see `casper.on received click event` somewhere, but it seems that it didn't get triggered:

```
$ casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=no google_click_test.js
seeking main page
found search form
clicked search button
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your example runs fine for me using casperjs 1.1.0-beta3 and phantomjs 1.9.8, I've been having similar issues in the last few months with casperjs. Sadly it seems that the author has stopped maintaining the project. More information here:

https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/1299

I would suggest moving to a different testing framework. In my case I chose a combination of mocha + chai + nightmarejs. This gist is a good starting point:

https://gist.github.com/MikaelSoderstrom/4842a97ec399aae1e024

Comment: Point well taken.  Oddly, Im running the same combo as you (casperjs 1.1.0.beta-3 and phantomjs 1.9.8).  Not sure why our results are different.

Comment: You can also try listening for `remote.message`, `resource.error` and `page.error` events. Maybe phantomjs can't load the page properly or something. I would also suggest running it on a dead-simple local page and fire up some console messages, then listen to `remote.message` events to see if you can at least get some event handler to respond.